# Grid VIew In ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

When i refresh the browser page grid view change the default bound data. How Can I Stop This?

In Grid View Properties I am applying the "AllowPaging" Property as "True"....

I have tried Auto Post Back Method But This Is Not Working For Me For Solve This Problem.

Comment: you should show the code also, in order to look what is happening

Comment: my grid view is bind with sqldatasource in aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your ASPX file

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    allowpaging="true"
    PageSize="50" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging"
/>
```

Here is how you handle paging:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
string connStr = "connectionstring";
string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM Table1;";
DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
try {
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)) {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
                myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
                GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewPageIndex);
            }
            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks #artisdextrus but i have already done this this code not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you already use !IsPostBack() method. It is used to controlled the browser refresh.
Cheers!

private void Page_Load()

{

```
if (!IsPostBack)

{

    //You can write here the code, which you want to execute in the first time when the page is loaded.

    FunctionToBindSomething();

}
```

}